# Android OpenCV undefined refrence to native class

Tags: android, c++, opencv, android-ndk

I create my android project as instruction in openCv reference and configure my project, add java in SDK as Module and copy all libs (different CPU types) in jinLibs! I have one native class named `libdetection_based_tracker`

When I try to build my project I got this exception:

```
CMakeFiles/libdetection_based_tracker.dir/src/main/cpp/libdetection_based_tracker.cpp.o: In function `Java_ir_whiteapp_maremat_DetectionBasedTracker_nativeCreateObject':
G:\AR\Maremat\app\src\main\cpp/libdetection_based_tracker.cpp:28: undefined reference to `DetectionBasedTracker::Parameters::Parameters()'
G:\AR\Maremat\app\src\main\cpp/libdetection_based_tracker.cpp:31: undefined reference to `DetectionBasedTracker::DetectionBasedTracker(std::string const&, DetectionBasedTracker::Parameters const&)'
CMakeFiles/libdetection_based_tracker.dir/src/main/cpp/libdetection_based_tracker.cpp.o: In function `Java_ir_whiteapp_maremat_DetectionBasedTracker_nativeSetFaceSize':
G:\AR\Maremat\app\src\main\cpp/libdetection_based_tracker.cpp:64: undefined reference to `DetectionBasedTracker::getParameters()'
G:\AR\Maremat\app\src\main\cpp/libdetection_based_tracker.cpp:66: undefined reference to `DetectionBasedTracker::setParameters(DetectionBasedTracker::Parameters const&)'
CMakeFiles/libdetection_based_tracker.dir/src/main/cpp/libdetection_based_tracker.cpp.o: In function `cv::Mat::operator=(cv::Mat const&)':
```

here is my app level gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ir.whiteapp.maremat"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags ""
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
    sourceSets { main { jni.srcDirs = ['src/main/jni', 'src/main/jniLibs/'] } }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile project(':openCVLibrary320')
}
```

and my CmakeList

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

include_directories(src/main/jniLibs/jni/include)
add_library( lib_opencv SHARED IMPORTED )
set_target_properties(lib_opencv PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/jniLibs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libopencv_java3.so)
add_library( native-lib SHARED src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp )
add_library( libdetection_based_tracker SHARED src/main/cpp/libdetection_based_tracker.cpp )

find_library( # Sets the name of the path variable.
          log-lib

          # Specifies the name of the NDK library that
          # you want CMake to locate.
          log )

target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
                   native-lib

                   # Links the target library to the log library
                   # included in the NDK.
                   ${log-lib} )
```

the whole project is [here](https://github.com/makbn/OpenCV_sample_android_studio) without jinLibs file! this is my first attempt to work with NDK and OpenCV, then ask me if one part of my question is vague!

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/asmlibrary/F6Wm4IjaBZg), The Android.mk must look like this:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := asmlibrary

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := so/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libasmlibrary.so #must be included
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY) 

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

#OPENCV_CAMERA_MODULES:=off
#OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=off
#OPENCV_LIB_TYPE:=SHARED

include /youropencv/OpenCV-2.4.6-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk

LOCAL_SRC_FILES  := DemoFit.cpp

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)
LOCAL_CFLAGS    += -DOPENCV_OLDER_VISION #(if still get errors, disable OPENCV_OLDER_VISION )

LOCAL_LDLIBS     += -llog -ldl  

LOCAL_MODULE     := jni-asmlibrary

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := asmlibrary

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: I download OpenCV 3.2.0 but my lib folder doesn't contain libasmlibrary.so!! is it necessary for my project??